# Oracle - Refactor subquery with max()

Tags: sql, oracle, refactoring, subquery, analytic-functions

I have the query below.  SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT_CYCLE has multiple rows, but I'm interested in the latest.

I would like to rewrite the query so that I don't use a subquery.  I have attempted it with DENSE_RANK LAST ORDERY BY, but to no avail.

Could somebody advise?  Thank you.

```
SELECT SOF.VENDOR, 
       SOF.NAME, 
       LAN.LANGUAGE, 
       SOF.VERSION, 
       SDC.STATUS, 
       SDC.SOF_DC_ID
  FROM SOFTWARE SOF
  JOIN SOFTWARE_LANGUAGES SL 
    ON (SL.SOF_SOF_ID = SOF.SOF_ID)
  JOIN LANGUAGES LAN 
    ON (SL.LAN_LAN_ID = LAN.LAN_ID)
  JOIN SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT_CYCLE SDC 
    ON (SDC.SOF_LAN_SOF_LAN_ID = SL.SOF_LAN_ID)
 WHERE SDC.SOF_DC_ID IN (SELECT MAX(SDC2.SOF_DC_ID)
                           FROM SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT_CYCLE SDC2
                          WHERE SDC2.SOF_LAN_SOF_LAN_ID = SL.SOF_LAN_ID)
 ORDER BY SOF.VENDOR, 
          SOF.NAME, 
          LAN.LANGUAGE, 
          SOF.VERSION;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this to avoid having to hit the `SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT_CYCLE` table a second time

```
SELECT vendor,
       name,
       language,
       version,
       status,
       sof_dc_id
  FROM (SELECT SOF.VENDOR, 
               SOF.NAME, 
               LAN.LANGUAGE, 
               SOF.VERSION, 
               SDC.STATUS, 
               SDC.SOF_DC_ID,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sl.sdf_lan_id 
                                ORDER BY sdc.sdf_dc_id DESC) rnk
          FROM SOFTWARE SOF
          JOIN SOFTWARE_LANGUAGES SL 
            ON (SL.SOF_SOF_ID = SOF.SOF_ID)
          JOIN LANGUAGES LAN 
            ON (SL.LAN_LAN_ID = LAN.LAN_ID)
          JOIN SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT_CYCLE SDC 
            ON (SDC.SOF_LAN_SOF_LAN_ID = SL.SOF_LAN_ID))
 WHERE rnk = 1
 ORDER BY VENDOR, 
          NAME, 
          LANGUAGE, 
          VERSION;
```

The `RANK` analytic function is partitioning the result set by `sl.sdf_lan_id`.  Then for each distinct `sl.sdf_lan_id`, it is assigning a numeric rank to the row based on the descending order of `sdc.sdf_dc_id`.  That means that the row with the largest `sdc.sdf_dc_id` for a particular `sl.sdf_lan_id` will have a `RANK` of 1.  The outer `WHERE rnk=1` predicate then selects only the rows that have that maximum value.  That should accomplish the same thing that your `MAX` subquery is accomplishing.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you explain your process in deciding how to do that?